# How can I add an item to a list and return a new list

Tags: c#

I was asked this question today:

> How can I add an item to a list and return that list back?

The code for `List<T>.Add(T)` returns void.  So you can't do something like this:

```
var list = new List<string>{"item1","item2"};
var newList = list.Add("item3");
```

This is related to using AutoMapper, although that part isn't particularly important.

Comment: Why would you want to create a new list? Why not add to the list and keep referring to the original?

Comment: The problem, I believe is in Automapper, instead of creating a custom resolver you could do it in one line: `ForMember(t=>t.Items,options=>options.MapFrom(s=>new List<string>(t.Items).Add(s.Item));`  t.Items is an existing list in an object, possibly with existing data, however, we just want to append the value from the source.  Unfortunately, this particular line requires your to return a value so that Automapper can set it to the property.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One option is Linq, with [`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb302894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var list = new List<string>{"item1", "item2"};
var newList = list.Concat(new[] { "item3" }).ToList();
```

In typical Linq fashion, `list` stays the same, and `newList` contains all the items from `list` as well as the items in the new list, in this case just `"item3"`.

You can skip the `.ToList()` to keep the `IEnumerable<string>` result if that fits your use case.

---

If you find yourself doing this often with individual items, you can use something like this extension method to pass them without the `new[] { ... }` syntax:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params T[] items)
{
    return source.Concat(items);
}
```

Because of the `params` array the earlier example becomes:

```
var list = new List<string>{"item1", "item2"};
var newList = list.ConcatItems("item3").ToList();
```

---

Make sure not to mix this up with [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341731%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which removes duplicate items. (Searching for those duplicates is overhead that you probably don't want!)

Comment: I really like this one, I hadn't thought of the `Concat` function!

Comment: I take what i said in my answer back.  This is just as readable and more concise.  +1

Answer (score 19):

The answer to this question was relatively simple:

```
var list = new List<string>(new List<string>{"item1","item2"}){"item3"};
```

`List<T>()` has a constructor that can take in `IEnumerable<T>` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx)).  Additionally, you can use the object setter to put new items into the list.

So, for a more complicated example:

```
var originalList = new List<string>();
originalList.Add("item1");
originalList.Add("item2");

var newList = new List<string>(originalList){"item3"};
```

Comment: I don't completely understand how this answers the first statement in your post (How can I add an item to a list and return that list back?). This creates a new list which seems pointless. Especially since that statement asks for "that list back" which I assume is the one you added to. Or am I misinterpreting that statement?

Comment: @DangerZone I will clarify in my question, the statement "that list back" refers to the list of items not necessarily the same reference.

Comment: this is the answer with the most concise syntax. using the constructor and the setter during initialization perfectly solves the problem!

Comment: @JasonWilczak this is the best way that I know of, but is there a more performant alternative? If the return type is IReadOnlyList<T> then that could allow for array results too.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do :

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{"item1","item2"};
List<string> newList = null;

(newList = list.ToList()).Add("item3");
```

Or create your own extension method :

```
public static class Helper 
{
   public static List<T> MyAdd<T>(this List<T> collection, T item)
   {
      collection.Add(item);
      return collection;
   }
}
```

And use it :

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{"item1","item2"};
List<string> newList = list.MyAdd("item3"); // same object though
List<string> newList2 = newList.ToList().MyAdd("item4").MyAdd("item5"); // different object
```

Answer (score 2):

One property of an [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.111).aspx) (and other similar data structures from `System.Collections.Immutable`) is that it doesn't mutate the original list, it returns another immutable list with the added value.

So doing this:

```
var originalImmutable = ImmutableList<int>.Create(1, 2);
var otherImmutable = originalImmutable.Add(3);
```

Will result in a shallow copied new list each time you call `Add`.

Comment: I think the most important aspect of this answer is that the performance of `List<T>` and `ImmutableList<T>` for different operations is very different, and while there are cases where `List<T>` is faster, this is one where `ImmutableList<T>` is much, much faster, especially when the first list is large.

Answer (score 1):

Seven years have passed since the question has been asked but [Enumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable) class now offers [Prepend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend) and [Append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append) methods that could be used in a straightforward fashion:

```
var list = new List<string>{"item1","item2"};
var newList = list.Append("item3").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The most readable and maintainable solution is to copy the list and then add the item:

```
var list = new List<string>{"item1","item2"};
var newList = list.toList();
newList.Add("item3");
```